# preload map tiles before drawing

Tags: javascript, html, preloader, createjs

I'm creating a browser based game with javascript (createJS) and HTML5 canvas... and am working on the tilemap drawings.

I would like to preload all tiles before drawing them.

```
function start() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true; 
    if (preloadMap()) {
        log("all loaded");
        createMap();
    }
    else {
        log("error loading tiles");
    }
    ... more stuff


var loadArr = [],
    images = [
        "images/tile.png",
        "images/tile2.png"
    ],
    loadedImages = [];


function preloadMap() {

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        loadArr[i] = false;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        loadedImages[i] = img;
        img.src = images[i];
        img.onload = (function(i) {
            return function() { loadArr[i] = true }
        })(i);      
    }
}
```

If preloadMap comes back true for all load images, then I call `createMap()`:

```
function createMap() {
    background = new createjs.Container();      
    for (var y = 0; y < mapArray.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < mapArray[y].length; x++) {
            if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 0) {
                var tile = new createjs.Bitmap(loadedImages[0]);
            }
            if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 1) {
                var tile = new createjs.Bitmap(loadedImages[1]);    
            }
            tile.x = x * 28;
            tile.y = y * 28;
            background.addChild(tile);
        }
    }
    background.cache(0, 0, 1000, 1000); 
    stage.addChild(background);     
}
```

Getting error: `error loading tiles` But not sure why

Comment: Why do you expect `preloadMap()` to return a boolean?

Comment: Check out PreloadJS. It works quite well with EaselJS content. http://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS http://preloadjs.com

Comment: @Lanny Thanks. I tried following this example http://nightlycoding.com/index.php/2012/09/image-slideshow-with-preloadjs-jquery-and-tweenmax/, and it kept giving me errors. And the video provided here on http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS, "Getting Started with Create JS", the guy doesn't talk about Preload at all. I'm not sure what preload is or does. It's not immediately clear like easeljs or soundjs.